# weird output using foreach command

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

So I am trying to familiarize myself with tikz \foreach command through [this link](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse15.html) Yet something strange happened. According the the linke, if I am trying to iterize two variable at the same time instead of one after the other, I should use */* to separate the two.
Thus a code like

```
\foreach \x / \y in {1/2,a/b} {``\x\ and \y''}
```

should yield

```
“1 and 2”“a and b”
```

But when I typed in the exact same code, instead I got a bland page.

Here is my code for reproducing purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\tikz
\foreach \x / \y in {1/2,a/b} {``\x\ and \y''};



\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Why `\tikz`? You aren’t drawing a picture.

Comment: `\tikz` just drops the text as it is not in a node. Either drop `\tikz`, or use nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I compile your example code, I find in the log file

```
Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ' in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ' in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ' in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ' in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
```

which means that TeX is indeed trying to typeset the letters, but since it is in the middle of a `tikzpicture`, it has been instructed to use the `nullfont`, which is an internal font that has no character at all and produces no interword space either.

If I remove `\tikz` and the semicolon, I get

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know Tizpicture environment doesn't allow text,